# Python byte string print incorrectly in dictionary

Tags: python, string, byte

Consider a list contains data in byte (i.e ['\x03', '\x00', '\x32', ... ])

```
temp = b''

for c in field_data:
   temp += c
   print "%x" % ord(c)
```

above code correctly concatenates all bytes into temp (byte string literal). But when I added this into element of dictionary, output was incorrect in some cases.

```
testdic = {'dd':temp}
print testdic
```

For example, 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x33 0x32 are in list and first code show all bytes were correctly concatenated. But when I executed second code right after, output was like this:

```
{'dd': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0032'}
```

And I'm not entirely sure why this happens.

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print a `dict`, it prints the braces `{` and `}` along with a **representation** of the contents.

```
>>> b = b'\x00\x0f\xff'
>>> print b
�
>>> print repr(b)
'\x00\x0f\xff'
>>> print {'test':b}
{'test': '\x00\x0f\xff'}
```

**EDIT**

The numbers 0x33 & 0x32 are the ASCII values of the characters '3' and '2'. `repr` will show printable ascii characters directly, while using the `\x00` notation for non-printable characters.

```
>>> b = b'\x33\x32'
>>> print b
32
>>> print repr(b)
'32'
>>> hex(ord('3'))
'0x33'
```

Here's a function that I use for printing hex representations of strings

```
>>> def hexstr(s):
...     return '-'.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in s)
...
>>> hexstr(b'\x00\xff\x33\x32')
'00-ff-33-32'
```

You might be able to subclass `dict` and override the `__str__` representation if you want this to happen automatically.

Comment: AH i see why that happened. What if I want to do '\x32\x33' ?